# create a blank database from a production database programmatically

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing

For software testing purposes I would like to create a sterile clone (with all data blanked out) of the production database. This way I can run my unit tests on a known set of records every time. I am looking to try and do this programmatically within the unit tests themselves so I can ensure that the tables contain exactly the test data that I need for the functional tests.

I have found the following [information](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/268147-create-access-database-c) relating to creating an Access database within C#. Note: I know Access probably isn't the best solution, but its good enough!

What I would like to know, is there a way of using TableAdapters (perhaps) to replicate the production database schema (without any data) within a blank Access database file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

- create a copy of the access file; production -> test
- connect to test database
- [enumerate all tables](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/56908/list-all-tables-in-access-mdb-database----.aspx) in the database
- run `DELETE * FROM [table]` for all tables.  run it several times if you have FK dependencies until there is no error - or `TRUNCATE [table]` as commented
- [compact](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mdbcompact_latebind.aspx) the database

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much experience with Access, but generally you would make a CREATE script for this purpose. Most database tools have a function for creating such a script. Such a script basically is a set of SQL statements that create all the objects (e.g. databases, views).

Searching for [CREATE script and Access will give you some starting points](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=access+generate+create+script&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Answer (score 0):

I have bad experiences with Access as a production database. I won't recommend. Either go with SQLite or Firebird.

Secondly, yes you can use TableAdapters. You need to create two connections for each db. But I think there might be tools available to do this.

Edited **

How big is the database? For up to 4GB, Oracle Express Edition might help. Also, it will be easy to clone from Oracle to Oracle.

Comment: I should make it clear that the production database is an Oracle DB but for ease of use and portability I'm thinking that the Unit Test database's should be Access.

Comment: For testing you can use anything until and unless it has nothing to with the production environment.

Comment: Depending on the test (and your definition of "unit") I'd generally still attempt to replicate live as best you can. So have an Oracle instance and then something like dbunit to put it in a known state for test and shell scripts to make it "live minus data".

Comment: Just to clarify a the above. Oracle instance per developer. It does add a bit to maintenance but (IMO) it is worth while.

Comment: The Database is well below the 4GB limit of Oracle Express. I must admit its an interesting idea! although creating (or at least configuring) a Oracle server programmatically sounds like a large job!

Comment: @TK: Why you want to programatically create a database? Working with the same breed it more beneficial as datatypes are going to change with the breed.